# Automation of dashboards in Metabase on daily basis using SQL queries

Tags: sql, dashboard, metabase

I have to run SQL queries on daily basis to extract data and use those results to create a dashboard. I would like to automate this process i.e. dashboard should create automatically (on daily basis) and the result should be sent automatically across the team through email. Can I do this in Metabase? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

As for dashboard should create automatically (on daily basis), this is something could be done by metabase API. There is a open source Clojure library, [embedkit](https://github.com/lambdaisland/embedkit), can help you use the API more easily.

Not sure that if your database will be updated on daily basis. If so, there is [a solution](https://discourse.metabase.com/t/how-do-i-automatically-refresh-a-dashboard-when-the-database-is-updated/15927) to this on forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an email for your team on daily basis.

And about auto updates, you can write queries that retrieve your data for yesterday only, for example:

```
date = current_date - interval 1 day
```

and it will run daily by yesterday record only.